# Does upgrading up to iOS7 automatically change styles?

Tags: xcode, ios7

If I have an iOS5 or iOS6 app, once I build for iOS7, do all the buttons get iOS styling automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have any code that overwrites it, yes they will look iOS7-like.

For example, if you used [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] this will create a different button on iOS7 than it did on iOS6-.

Answer (score 0):

Your layout will change because the iphone 6 `width and height` are diffrent from iphone 7, and some control are also depreciated.